# Validating all controls together in a loop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation, loops

I'm using following method to validate user inputs in `TextBoxes` and `ComboBoxes` in each `GroupBox` of a Winform.

```
private bool ValidateControlsIn(GroupBox gb)
{
    foreach (Control c in gb.Controls.Cast<Control>().OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex))
    {
        if (c is TextBox || c is ComboBox)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Empty field {0 }", c.Name.Substring(3)));
                c.Focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Apart from `ComboBoxes` and `TextBoxes`, I have `RadioButtons` and 1CheckBoxes1 also to be validated.

So I have been trying to take them too into account when validating, without success.

Would it be possible to check `RadioButtons` and `Checkboxes` too in this same method/loop?

Comment: You could add an else if below the checking for Textboxes and then validate those.

Comment: What did you try?  Why did it not succeed?

Comment: @ Matthijs, But the problem is that which property to check for empty?  `c.value` / `c.Checked` / ??

Comment: @DonBoitnott, I tried to include new conditions in first If block after `|` like `c.value==false` etc. And to have `Else If` part etc etc.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?  Your comments on one of the answers don't align with what you've asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation can be performed in multiple different ways.  Before you commit yourself to writing your own method for validation, consider using the [Control.Validating / Control.Validated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event handlers and the [Form.ValidateChildren](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.FORM.VALIDATECHILDREN%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) method.  These provisions take a lot of bulk out of your work and add cancellation event arguments to halt the leave / lose focus process.

If you are committed to using your own foreach and iterating the controls, you have an alright idea, albeit it won't look nice when scaling it.

```
foreach (Control c in gb.Controls.Cast<Control>().OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex))
        {
            if (c is TextBox || c is ComboBox)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Empty field {0 }", c.Name.Substring(3)));
                    c.Focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if (c is RadioButton)
            {
                //handle me
                return false;
            }
            else if (c is CheckBox)
            {
                //handle me
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
```

Using the Validating / Validated provisions available you could add a custom handler to each control type, or each individual control.  This allows you to keep you method definitions smaller and more modular.  Take the following example.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // fires validating events for all controls that are selectable.
        // other constraints are available.
        this.ValidateChildren(ValidationConstraints.Selectable);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the validating for a single control or multiple controls.
    /// Depends on the registration.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="CancelEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        bool condition = true;
        if (!condition)
        {
            // remaining validation and leave stack will not be performed.
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles post validation for a single control or multiple controls.
    /// Depends on the registration.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void textBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // handle after validation logic here.
        // spray happy faces all over the world.
    }
```

I hope this gives you a decent answer to your question, and an alternative that might look and act a bit cleaner.

Comment: In the foreach approach, if we don't want to use messagebox, what else can be done? something more stylish, Like messages in text box and color changed, instead of a bunch of messages one after the other.

Answer (score 1):

Use else if to check others:

```
if (c is TextBox || c is ComboBox)
{
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.Text))
      {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Empty field {0 }", c.Name.Substring(3)));
            c.Focus();
            return false;
      }
}
else if(c is RadioButton)
{
      // Logic
}
else if(c is CheckBox)
{
      // Logic
}
```

If you want to actually target them, cast them to their types:

```
RadioButton rdb = c as RadioButton;
CheckBox cb = c as CheckBox;
```

Example:

```
else if(c is RadioButton)
{
     RadioButton rd = c as RadioButton;
     if(rd != null)
     {
           if(!rd.Checked)
                // Do something
     }
}
```

In retrospect you could actually cast C into a RadioButton as you already checked if it is one: `RadioButton rd = (RadioButton)c` and then skip the `rd != null`

Comment: The issue is not all the `RadioButtons / CheckBoxes` in the form are supposed to be `checked`. For ex: If we have two `radioButtons` called `Male` and `Female`, only one of them should be checked? How to address this issue?

Comment: Put them inside a `GroupBox` control. Or use the `CheckedChangedevent`, if a.Checked is true, set b.Checked to false.